# Remove the 00:00:00.000 from a sales query MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

Im trying to find out how i can remove 00:00:00.000 from my monthly sales date, so it gets even more easy for my economic brothers.

When i do my:

```
select SALES_DATE from SALES
where SALES_DATE BETWEEN '2013-11-02' and '2013-12-01'
```

i get the dates formatted as: 2013-11-28 00:00:00.000 
while i really want it as 2013-11-28

any ideas?

Comment: Try `DATE(SALES_DATE)`, but have to add that this question shows no effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE(SALES_DATE) FROM SALES
WHERE DATE(SALES_DATE) 
BETWEEN '2013-11-02' AND '2013-12-01'
```

Thus using the Date function, you can get your date in the required format.

Here, we are explicitly converting it.

The different date format is because of the sql date and util date which is implicit.

Comment: Im sorry brother, but i get 'DATE' is not a recognised built-in function name.

Comment: Try using casting   CAST(SALES_DATE AS DATE)

Comment: I suggest you remove the `DATE()` function from the `WHERE` clause: it doesn't help the formatting problem you have and it will prevent index usage (if any exists) on `SALES_DATE` column. You only need it on the `SELECT` clause. If you want to catch boundary values (i.e. ignore time) change your query parameters as `BETWEEN '2013-11-02' AND '2013-12-01 23:59:59'`. This only applies if the table actually has index on this column and you have performance issues

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for **[DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)** function in mysql.

According to mysql documentation

> DATE(expr) Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression
>   expr. mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
>           -> '2003-12-31'

So your case will be

```
select DATE(SALES_DATE) from SALES
where SALES_DATE BETWEEN '2013-11-02' and '2013-12-01'
```

Comment: Nope. outer boundary may fail.

Comment: True, but OP doesn't mention boundary values issues, just formatting. Also, boundary values can be handled by including time in parameters or switching `BETWEEN` with `>=` & `<` operators

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)** function.

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(SALES_DATE) 
FROM SALES
WHERE DATE(SALES_DATE) BETWEEN '2013-11-02' AND '2013-12-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MySQL`'s build in functions such as `DATE_FORMAT()` or even `DATE()`

```
SELECT DATE(SALES_DATE) FROM SALES
WHERE DATE(SALES_DATE) BETWEEN '2013-11-02' AND '2013-12-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Date_FORMAT function
Try this..

```
select DATE_FORMAT(SALES_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") from SALES
where SALES_DATE BETWEEN '2013-11-02' and '2013-12-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(SALES_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d") 
FROM SALES
where SALES_DATE BETWEEN '2013-11-02' and '2013-12-01'
```

## [FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/30538)